# Query SDE to display records created for 'X' date/time

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I am looking to query our SDE to display feature classes modified beginning from January 1, 2013 to today.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and as it stands searching through dbo tables but can't find any information that would display feature classes modified.

The purpose is to build a business case by identifying a volume of edits/modifications to our data over time.

[image: Below is an image of my work environment]

Comment: For Oracle, but might be of interest: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21614/tracking-change-with-arcsde-oracle

Comment: Are you looking to display shapefiles or enterprise geodatabase feature classes?  If it's shapefiles, you should be looking at filesystem timestamps.

Comment: My bad. I should have clarified. I am looking for feature class information. I will adjust my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar using our Oracle SDE Geodatabase:

http://socalgis.org/2014/03/26/sde-geodatabase-feature-class-where-is-the-modified-date/

You could modify it for SQL Server and change the SQL statement to pull out a date range.  Let me know if you get it working for SQL Server.

Comment: The methodology here is enough to get me going using SQL. Much appreciated! once I have the kinks worked out I will post it back here for future users.